# Ajax form is not going through when using Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, bootstrap-4, ajaxform

When I'm on the form it says that it has been submitted, but it don't receive it in my email.  It works fine with Chrome and MS Edge.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

I have uploaded the newest version of Java, but when I reference the new version in the .html file, it comes up with a blank web page. 

 or  so it is not happy with the new version. I thought that might be the problem with Mozilla, but I'm not sure.

JS file:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   //Captcha
   $('.captcha-button').click(function() {
     $( ".not-a-robot-text" ).fadeOut( 500 );
     $( ".not-a-robot-icon i" ).delay( 499 ).fadeIn( 500 );
     $( ".captcha-button" ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 0 );
     $( ".button-parent" ).html( '<button style="display:none" class="submit-form button border-radius l=12 text-white background-orange" type="submit">Submit Button</button>' );
     $( ".submit-form.button" ).delay( 1500 ).fadeIn( 0 );   
   });

   $('.ajax-form').each(function(index, element) {
       $(this).submit(function(e) {

           //Stop form submission & check the validation
           e.preventDefault();
           window.error = false;           
           //text, textarea
           $(element).find('.required').each(function() {           
               // Variable declaration               
               var required = $(element).find(this);
               var required_val = $(element).find(this).val();


               // Form field validation 
               if (required_val.length == 0) {
                   window.error = true;
                   $(this).parent().find('.form-error').fadeIn(500);
                   $(element).find('.mail-success').fadeOut(500);
               } else { 
                   $(this).parent().find('.form-error').fadeOut(500);
                   $(element).find('.mail-fail').fadeOut(500);  
               }
           });

           //email
           $(element).find('.email').each(function() {           
               // Variable declaration               
               var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
               var email = $(this).val();   
               // Form field validation 
               if (!filter.test(email)) {
                   window.error = true; 
                   $(this).parent().find('.form-error').fadeIn(500);
                   $(element).find('.mail-success').fadeOut(500);
               } else { 
                   $(this).parent().find('.form-error').fadeOut(500);
                   $(element).find('.mail-fail').fadeOut(500);  
               }
           });            

           // If there is no validation error, next to process the mail function
           if (window.error == false) {
                var formObj = $(this);
                var formURL = formObj.attr("action");
                var formData = new FormData(this);
                $.ajax ({
                    url: 'resp-csa2.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:  formData,
                    mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    //If the email is sent successfully, reset form
                    $(element).each(function() {
                       this.reset();
                    });
                    //Display the success message
                    $(element).find('.mail-success').fadeIn(500);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    //Display the error message
                    $(element).find('.mail-success').fadeOut(500);
                    $(element).find('.mail-fail').fadeIn(500);
                }          
                });
                e.preventDefault(); //Prevent Default action. 
                e.unbind();
            }   
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: Check the network tab in your Firefox dev tools. Does it say anything about the AJAX request you've made?

Comment: Nothing in  "red", but I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: When I submit the form, the Web Developer Network section shows POST and File resp-csa2.php and Cause shows xhr

Comment: Side question; what are you trying to do with this?  `var required_val = $(element).find(this).val();` ?

Comment: I'm suspicious of `window.error`. Maybe that's a built-in property on Mozilla. Why are you using that instead of a local variable?

Comment: there is a GlobalEventHandlers.onerror but not a *.error from mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Comment: I don't understand the reference to Java. Surey this is all about JavaScript?